# What is the Struts 2 tag to create a table?

Tags: struts2

How do I create a table with fixed header and scrolling rows in struts 2?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the s:iterate tag to create a table, 
with simple iteration of an collection.

An other way is to use [Display Tag Libary](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/) for static Tables
or the [Grid Tags](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag) from [Struts2 jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/). with both you 
can simple implement paging and sorting.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, Struts2 does not provide such things, it's easy to write it by yourself.
You can also try to use DisplayTags on top of Struts2 (I haven't, google for it)

Answer (score 0):

You can change theme struts to simple and then easy to code html in struts.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-override-default-theme/

Answer (score 0):

As noted above there is no struts 2 table tag, but one suggestion would be the www.jtable.org. It is a jQuery plugin I use with struts 2 for our admin functionality to display our information.

Note: I do not use the jtable generated forms, since they do not match our need and style. We have also built an integration class to fit our needs.